# Synchronous api tasks on Python Flask

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, synchronous

I know that we cannot make async calls using Flask. Flask supports synchronous calls. Does that mean a user's request waits the other requests that started before?

For example, I have a post method like this and assume that update method takes 10 seconds to execute:

```
@app.route('/update', methods = ['POST'])
def update():
    # CODE
```

Assume that 100 users are making a post request on update method at the same time. The 100th user will wait for the previous requests (99 users * 10 sec = 990 seconds)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, depending on what you mean by "async", yes, you can make HTTP requests to a Flask app that arranges to do work asynchronously. That's what tasks queues like [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) and [Rq](https://github.com/rq/rq) are for. There's a good walk-through of using Rq in chapter 22 of the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

Second, if you only have a single process, single thread web server, then yes, requests are handled sequentially. In practice, though, you'll deploy behind something like `uwsgi` or `gunicorn`, which manage multiple processes running your app.

Comment: I am using postgre sql, my flask api handles CRUD operations. If i use gunicorn to serve my flask app, 10 create requests at the same time will handle async right? 10 requests starts at the same time and finishes almost at the same time?

Comment: How requests can run in parallel depends on how many processes you've told gunicorn to use. Assuming you're running the same request, and that the request doesn't involve some other bottleneck, they should finish at about the same time. PostgreSQL handles simultaneous requests just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually Yes you are correct but in the real world, it depends on your deployment of
the flask application

Like we use Gunicorn which is a WSGI HTTP Server that usually lives between a reverse proxy Nginx and a web application such as Django or Flask.
Gunicorn spawns a number of workers and The role of the workers is to handle HTTP requests.

Comment: Does this mean we don't necessarily need Celery unless our application is quite big?